# Django create s3 bucket with button

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a button which will create an S3 bucket in AWS once clicked. I am still a bit green when it comes to Django so I'm not sure how to get this to run. I read a few tutorials but all of them show how to add something to a database when clicking a button.
Here's what I have done so far:

views.py

```
class createS3(TemplateView):
template_name = 'project/create_s3.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = S3Form()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def createBucket(self, bucketName):
    form = S3Form(request.POST)
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=name)

def post(self, request):
    form = S3Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    args = {'form':form, 'name':name}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Here's the template:

```
{% include "home/_header.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
 <div class="mainPage">
   <div class="s3Wrapper">
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" name="create" class="button create">Create</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Now my problem is, how do I call the `createBucket` function by clicking the button? Or do I need to create a new url and pass the 'name' variable there to create a new bucket?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why aren't you doing something like this:

```
def createBucket(self, bucketName):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucketName)

def post(self, request):
    form = S3Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        self.createBucket(name)
    ...
```

Comment: Looks like it would work but when I hit submit button I get `name 'createBucket' is not defined`. What does this mean? I have defined the function earlier, didn't I?

Comment: Assuming that both createBucket() and post() are methods on the same class, I've updated the code.

Comment: Cheers! Now I get another error but I guess this thread's issue has been resolved.  At least I now know how to use this.

Comment: Glad it helped. What you're running into here is actually knowing how to use classes in Python, rather than anything to do with Django or AWS or boto3. Good luck with the rest of the project.